# datetimepicker display format in jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have 2 datepicker startDate and endDate. If I opn datepicker it has defaultly showing the today's date fo both startDate and endDate.

For example, if I select "25-10-2016" from startDate, the endDate should be start from "25-10-2016". Not todays  date.

[image] [image]

Please look at this image,the active blue color date. Defaultly it has showing today's date for both startDate and endDate field.

The selected startDate as not todays's date. I want that startdate as endDate. Please help me how can I do this.

Comment: May be you need to initialize two different datepickers.

Answer (score 0):

> You can set the minimum date of EndDate like as below code. After that
>   endate date will always greater or equal to startdate.

```
 $("startdate").datepicker({
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            if(this.id == 'StartDate') {
                var minDate = selectedDate + 1;
                $('#to').datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate);
            }
        }
   });
```